# How do free webhosters enforce ads?

Tags: html, hosting, web-hosting

How do those webhosting companies enforce ads on your page?
I'd love to enforce a specific piece of html code on a webserver.
So, how do they?

Comment: check the source or use a debugger.

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say by showing hosted content in an `iframe`.  Any other approach would be vulnerable to having the ads defeated either by clever CSS or JavaScript on the hosted page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They might use append and prepend depending on the exact solution you are referring to.

You basically use it to call another file (html, php etc) which is appended or prepended on the page (At the top or botton).

I did it once years ago and it worked.

Maybe stick the adsense code in the appended/prepended file.

See: http://www.maheshchari.com/php-auto-append-prepend-file-using-htaccess/

James